# ALC1220 on z390 aorus master

Tags: 18.04, sound

I have z390 aorus master and i struggle to make ALC1220 working. I have no sound from the front speakers. I try to make an analog 5.1 system to work. The hardware works ok on windows 10 and on mac mojave.
Thank you!

Comment: yeah the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can get sound if I open up alsamixer then crank the headphones up to full.  Problem is that I have to do this after every reboot.  The speakers are in the right jack.  It's weird.

edit:  I just found out on another site that you can use:

sudo alsactl store   ## to store your alsamixer settings.

sudo alsa restore    ## to restore saved settings